# Can a numpy matrix be converted to database table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpython

Can a numpy matrix created within a plpython function be converted into a database table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dbTable` library to store a numpy array as a table. Please refer to the complete documentation - https://pypi.org/project/dbTable/